# Static factory method for trait

Tags: rust, factory-method

*I'm just learning Rust, so maybe I just didn't get some concepts correctly.*

I have a trait with some implementations:

```rust
trait Abstract {
    fn name(&self) -> &str;
}

struct Foo {}
struct Bar {}
struct Baz {}

impl Abstract for Foo {
    fn name(&self) -> &str { "foo" }
}
impl Abstract for Bar {
    fn name(&self) -> &str { "bar" }
}
impl Abstract for Baz {
    fn name(&self) -> &str { "baz" }
}
```

I want to add a static method to this trait to create some standard implementation by name:

```rust
trait Abstract {
    fn new(name: &str) -> Self {
        match name {
            "foo" => Foo{},
            "bar" => Bar{},
            "baz" => Baz{},
        }
    }
    fn name(&self) -> &str;
}
```

But this code doesn't compile because:

```
6 |     fn new(name: &str) -> Self {
  |                           ^^^^ doesn't have a size known at compile-time
```

I tried to use return `fn new(name: &str) -> impl Abstract` and
`fn new<T: Abstract>(name: &str) -> T` - but these variants doesn't work too with another errors.

What is the correct way exist of creating factory method for trait in Rust?

Comment: In Rust, you usually don't use a factory method. It seems like an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In Rust, every variable must be a single specific type. This is different to OO languages where a variable can have a type `Foo`, and that means that the variable contains a `Foo`, or any subclass of `Foo`.

Rust doesn't support this. If a variable has a type `Foo`, it *must* contain a `Foo` (ignoring any unsafe concerns).

Rust also doesn't support using traits as types (without the `dyn` keyword).

In your example, you have:

```rust
trait Abstract {
  fn new(name: &str) -> Self {
    // ...
  }
}
```

The return type `Self` here means "whatever type this trait is being implemented on". However, by providing a body in the trait definition, you're providing a default implementation, so this function should in theory apply to any type, and so the compiler has no information about the real concrete type `Self`, and therefore the `Sized` bound it not met (which in practice is very restrictive and probably not what you want).

If you want a function that takes a string and returns "some type `T` that implements `Abstract`", you could use a "trait object", which would look roughly like:

```rust
// outside trait definition
fn new_abstract(name: &str) -> Box<dyn Abstract> {  // dyn keyword opts into dynamic dispatch with vtables
  match name {
    "foo" => Box::new(Foo {}),
    // ...
  }
}
```

However, I'd warn against this pattern. Dynamic dispatch has some runtime overhead, and prevents many compile-time optimizations. Instead, there may be a more "rusty" way of doing it, but it's hard to tell without more context.

In general, constructing a type based on the value of a string smells like a bit of an anti-pattern.

Comment: Thanks you for this answer. My use case is based on determining a type (one of trait impl) based on user input (CLI option `--format=(plain|json)`. Does some common method exist in Rust to create such a type? maybe I'm thinking wrong way, like its working in other languages...

Comment: This sounds like you probably want an enum. You can define an enum that contains every possible option, and then `impl FromStr for MyEnum`. Then when you parse the CLI args you can call `argument.parse()` to get a `Result` which handles the case that the user enters an invalid string. If you're using a library like `clap`, check out their docs for details of how to use your own custom types

Answer (score 3):

- `fn new<T: Abstract>(…) -> T` means: `new` will return some concrete `T` that implements `Abstract`, and whatever calls `new` may decide which.
- `fn new() -> impl Abstract` means: `new` will return some concrete type of its choosing that implements Abstract, but whatever calls `new` won't know which concrete type. (But it must still be some single concrete type decided at compile-time, it can't be "Maybe `Foo` or maybe `Baz`")

If you absolutely want this, you can have a free function do your constructing:

```
trait Abstract {
    fn name(&self) -> &str;
}

fn new_abstract(name: &str) -> Box<dyn Abstract> {
    match name {
        "foo" => Box::new(Foo{}),
        "bar" => Box::new(Bar{}),
        "baz" => Box::new(Baz{}),
        _ => panic!("better not")
    }
}
```

The `new` function can't be part of `Abstract`, because you would get into trouble with [object safety](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/items/traits.html#object-safety). Essentially, if you want to return a `Box<dyn …>` of some trait, all the methods on the trait must be usable in dynamic dispatch, but `new` is not such a method.

Anyway, this is not a good idea. Adding a separate `new` function to `Foo`, `Bar`, and `Baz` is the Rust way to go.

Answer (score 3):

You can consider using an `enum` instead of dynamically dispatch it:

```rust
trait Abstract {
    fn name(&self) ->  &str;
    fn new(name: &str) -> Option<AbstractVariant> {
        match name {
            "foo" => Some(AbstractVariant::Foo(Foo {})),
            "bar" => Some(AbstractVariant::Bar(Bar {})),
            "baz" => Some(AbstractVariant::Baz(Baz {})),
            _ => None,
        }
    }
}

enum AbstractVariant {
    Foo(Foo),
    Bar(Bar),
    Baz(Baz),
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=9c6ab97de19c1e6c60350e5e86d4bfa9)

Comment: Wonder if https://docs.rs/enum_dispatch/latest/enum_dispatch/ would help here…